# How to find a backbone model inside a backbone collection by id?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I want to find a model by its id in a collection in backbone.

Here's a sample code:

```
model = Backbone.Model.extend({
});
collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model:model,
url:url,
});
myCollection = new collection();
myCollection.fetch();
myCollection.find({id:2}).toJSON();
```

I want to find the model with a specific id but it doesn't work like this?

I thinks the problem is that I can't use `find()` correctly.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is

```
myCollection.where({id:2})[0].toJSON();
```

see http://underscorejs.org/#where

Find actually takes a function as an argument (http://underscorejs.org/#find)

Comment: `where` returns an array not an object so `.toJSON()` won't work.
`myCollection.where({id:2})[0].toJSON();` is the correct form. @david_sulc

Answer (score 0):

Backbone already has a built in method to do this [`Collection.get(id)`](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Collection-get)